# Dúvida em relação a inclusão de cabeçalhos

Tags: c, include

É considerada uma "má pratica de programação" incluir um cabeçalho que já havia sido incluído em outro cabeçalho que incluí?

Ficou difícil entender a dúvida acima? Se sim, observe o código abaixo:

**#tst_1.h**

```
#ifndef TST_1_H
#define TST_1_H

//...código...e mais código...

#endif //TST_1_H
```

**#tst_2**

```
#ifndef TST_2_H
#define TST_2_H

#include "tst_1.h"

//...código...e mais código...

#endif //TST_2_H
```

**#main.c**

```
#include "tst_1.h"
#include "tst_2.h"

int main(void){

    //...faz alguma coisa...       

    return 0;
}
```

Observer que incluí `tst_1.h` no `main.c` sendo que `tst_2.h` já havia incluído ele dentro de sua defenição.

Então, isso é ou não é uma "má pratica de programação" em um programa escrito em C?

Comment: Se cada um dos `.h` tem o `#ifndef` ou `#pragma once` então por muitas inclusões que sejam feitas apenas a primeira vai valer, por isso no final do dia vai ser igual a nível do resultado final. A nível de boas práticas já poderá ser discutível.

Comment: Como dito pelo @Isac no comentário, a condição de guarda `#ifndef` pode ser usada para prevenir a inclusão de arquivos de cabeçalho duplicados.

Em termos de boas práticas, é interessante deixar sempre explícito o que você deseja importar em termos de dependências em vez de contar com dependências indiretas. Sendo assim, o seu arquivo `main.c` está de acordo. Qualquer pessoa pode simplesmente bater o olho na seção de includes e ver que existe uma dependência do arquivo `tst_1.h` sem ter que olhar para o arquivo `tst_2.h` antes.

Answer (score 1):

Pensando em boas praticas temos que nos colocar no lugar de outros programadores que irão ler nosso código.

Logo, para eles seria mais fácil ver uma biblioteca que chama diversas funções ou uma biblioteca especifica para cada tipo de funções?

Seria bem mais interessante deixar especificado no código principal cada biblioteca separadamente.